# Why the Code Bloat When Doing Arithmetic in C# Generic Class Using IBinaryArithmetic

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to be clever and use a generic class to perform the same arithmetic function across multiple data types with C# and .NET 7.  I noticed a significant performance hit and, in looking at the generated code, see that the arithmetic operators * and + are replaced by calls instead of using native imul and add instructions.  Can someone enlighten me on why this is happening, and if there is any way around the problem?

Source and disassembly code follow...

C# Source Code

```
using System.Numerics;

namespace ConsoleApp27 {

    internal class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var UIntInstance = new UIntClass(1, 1, 1);
            var ULongInstance = new ULongClass(1, 1, 1);
            var UInstance = new UClass<ulong>(1, 1, 1);
            UIntInstance.Step();
            ULongInstance.Step();
            UInstance.Step();
        }
    }

    public class UIntClass {
        public uint State;
        public uint Multiplier;
        public uint Increment;
        public UIntClass(uint state, uint multiplier, uint increment) {
            State = state;
            Multiplier = multiplier;
            Increment = increment;
        }
        public void Step() {
            State = State * Multiplier + Increment;
        }
    }

    public class ULongClass {
        public ulong State;
        public ulong Multiplier;
        public ulong Increment;
        public ULongClass(ulong state, ulong multiplier, ulong increment) {
            State = state;
            Multiplier = multiplier;
            Increment = increment;
        }
        public void Step() {
            State = State * Multiplier + Increment;
        }
    }

    public class UClass<T> where T : IBinaryInteger<T> {
        public T State;
        public T Multiplier;
        public T Increment;
        public UClass(T state, T multiplier, T increment) {
            State = state;
            Multiplier = multiplier;
            Increment = increment;
        }
        public void Step() {
            State = State * Multiplier + Increment;
        }
    }

}
```

Disassembly of (guts of) UIntClass Step() function

```
00007FFADD1A795D  mov         rax,qword ptr [rbp+10h]  
00007FFADD1A7961  mov         eax,dword ptr [rax+8]  
00007FFADD1A7964  mov         rdx,qword ptr [rbp+10h]  
00007FFADD1A7968  imul        eax,dword ptr [rdx+0Ch]  
00007FFADD1A796C  mov         rdx,qword ptr [rbp+10h]  
00007FFADD1A7970  add         eax,dword ptr [rdx+10h]  
00007FFADD1A7973  mov         rdx,qword ptr [rbp+10h]  
00007FFADD1A7977  mov         dword ptr [rdx+8],eax
```

Disassembly of (guts of) ULongClass Step() function

```
00007FFADD19902D  mov         rax,qword ptr [rbp+10h]  
00007FFADD199031  mov         rax,qword ptr [rax+8]  
00007FFADD199035  mov         rdx,qword ptr [rbp+10h]  
00007FFADD199039  imul        rax,qword ptr [rdx+10h]  
00007FFADD19903E  mov         rdx,qword ptr [rbp+10h]  
00007FFADD199042  add         rax,qword ptr [rdx+18h]  
00007FFADD199046  mov         rdx,qword ptr [rbp+10h]  
00007FFADD19904A  mov         qword ptr [rdx+8],rax
```

Disassembly of (guts of) UClass Step() function

```
00007FFADD1C9093  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+10h]  
00007FFADD1C9097  mov         qword ptr [rbp-10h],rcx  
00007FFADD1C909B  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+10h]  
00007FFADD1C909F  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rcx+8]  
00007FFADD1C90A3  mov         rdx,qword ptr [rbp+10h]  
00007FFADD1C90A7  mov         rdx,qword ptr [rdx+10h]  
00007FFADD1C90AB  call        qword ptr [CLRStub[MethodDescPrestub]@00007FFADD183978 (07FFADD183978h)]  
00007FFADD1C90B1  mov         qword ptr [rbp-18h],rax  
00007FFADD1C90B5  mov         rdx,qword ptr [rbp+10h]  
00007FFADD1C90B9  mov         rdx,qword ptr [rdx+18h]  
00007FFADD1C90BD  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp-18h]  
00007FFADD1C90C1  call        qword ptr [CLRStub[MethodDescPrestub]@00007FFADD1835A0 (07FFADD1835A0h)]  
00007FFADD1C90C7  mov         qword ptr [rbp-20h],rax  
00007FFADD1C90CB  mov         rax,qword ptr [rbp-10h]  
00007FFADD1C90CF  mov         rdx,qword ptr [rbp-20h]  
00007FFADD1C90D3  mov         qword ptr [rax+8],rdx
```

Comment: I'm not an expert at this particular domain but I believe it's because you aren't using a primitive datatype for UClass - it doesn't know how to optimize the call because by definition it's a class operation

Comment: Interface method calls cannot be inlined.  At the time the machine code is generated, just in time before the code starts running, the jitter doesn't yet know what object that implements the interface will be passed.

Comment: [Are you sure?](https://shorturl.at/DFGM2) they are almost the same ... maybe you use debug assembly

Comment: @RufusL https://sharplab.io/#v2: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